# How to use spin.js instead of a animated gif

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just looking for a bit of instruction really. I am very new to JQuery, so it's all a bit hazy.
However, I have a form "processing" div that shows [somewhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934803/show-div-upon-form-submit-works-in-chrome-ff-ie-but-not-safari) when a form has been submitted.

At the moment I have a simple div with a animated gif to visually show its sending.

```
<div id="loading">Please wait, your news is being submitted...
<img src="/-/images/addwalk-loader.gif"/>
```

Ideally, I would like to replace the animated gif with a spinner created through spin.js, as I am aware that animated gifs do not continue to animate on IE once the form has been sent.

The only problem is, looking through the documentation, I am a bit unsure as to how I would implement it. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If don't want to spin a current object as noted by Janus, you could instead create a new Spinner object and then position it on the page wherever you want it to be. For a list of options just check the docs!

Example:

```
var opts = {
   color: '#000'
   //etc etc
};
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin();
$("#loading").appendChild(spinner.el);
```

Heres a fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/vasco/6Ca8Y/

Comment: So would I call the script like I do my jQuery, and then add this to my jQuery file? Sorry Im probably sounding very useless, but I'm just not quite sure!

Comment: @shorn I updated the answer with a fiddle with a working example.

Comment: Ahh excellent! I haven't got time at the moment to try it out, but I think I should be able to work it out now. I'll message back once I've had a go tonight! Thanks!

Comment: Example above should be .append instead of .appendChild

Answer (score 3):

It's really quite easy. You call `.spin()` on the JQuery object that should spin. Call `.spin(false)` when you want it to stop.

I used it myself [here](https://github.com/ysangkok/androidprak/blob/master/botnetserver/static/tab.js).

Answer (score 1):

I found another plugin [Activity Indicator](http://neteye.github.io/activity-indicator.html) which have more options to customize and easy to integrate. Have a try :|